# Foreach loop through multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$results = [
    'cse' => [
        'students' => [
            [
                'name'=>'Safi', 'email'=>'info@safi' , 
                'result'=> [
                        '101' => 50,
                        '102' => 30
                    ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'bba' => [
        'students' => [
            [
                'name'=>'Rari', 'email'=>'info@rari' , 
                'result'=> [
                        '101' => 40,
                        '102' => 60
                    ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

**Expected Output:**

```
CSE result:
    Students: 
        Name: Safi
        Email: info@safi
        Result:
             1. 101 = 50
             2. 102 = 30

BBA result:
    Students :
```

Comment: ok, please show your attempt

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Let's do it:

```php
<?php
$results = [
    'cse' => [
        'students' => [
            [
                'name'=>'Safi', 'email'=>'info@safi' , 
                'result'=> [
                        '101' => 50,
                        '102' => 30
                    ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'bba' => [
        'students' => [
            [
                'name'=>'Rari', 'email'=>'info@rari' , 
                'result'=> [
                        '101' => 40,
                        '102' => 60
                    ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

function output($students) {
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        echo '        Name: ' . $student['name'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '        Email: ' . $student['email'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '        Result:' . PHP_EOL;
        
        $counter = 0;
        
        foreach ($student['result'] as $k => $v) {
            $counter++;
            echo '            ' . $counter . '. ' . $k . ' = ' . $v . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

echo 'CSE Results:' . PHP_EOL;
echo '    Students:' . PHP_EOL;
output($results['cse']['students']);

echo 'BBA Results:' . PHP_EOL;
echo '    Students:' . PHP_EOL;
output($results['bba']['students']);
```